# RewriteRule to only affect first segment

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following RewriteRule in place. This rewrites everything that starts with `mac`, `linux` or `windows`:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(mac|linux|windows) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/site/index/$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately this also rewrites `/mac/test/testing`. How can I prevent it from applying if there is another segmend after `/mac`?

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(linux|mac|windows)($|\/)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/site/index/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 ^(linux|mac|windows)/category/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/site/category/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 ^(app|download)/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/site/$1 [L]
```

Note the `$` sign at the end of the first line. I am not sure if `($|\/)` is the correct method to make a trailing slash optional but it works. Any advice?

Edit: There is actually a simpler way to handle the trailing slash.

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(linux|mac|windows)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/site/index/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The `RewriteCond` directives are superfluous, you can write it like this: `RewriteRule ^(linux|mac|windows)/?$ /index.php/site/index/$1 [NC,L]`